Varnish Cache Age Header Always 0 for Entire Page
I have installed Varnish on a remote server and configured it for my Drupal website. The Varnish headers show that requests are passing through the Varnish server for the entire page, but it is not caching the whole page. However, it works for some elements of the page.
enter image description here
I need help from someone

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The logs are going to give use more information on why the page is not being served from the cache.
Assuming it's the homepage, you can run the following varnishlog command to figure this out:
sudo varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"

If it's a different page that is experiencing this issue, please change the URL in the filter query.
Please attach the full log output for this transaction in pre-formatted text to your original question.
Please also attach the VCL file you're using for this Varnish installation.
